# libreoffice doesn't start

Tags: libreoffice

After I managed to make Ubuntu start properly and made it look OK I just realized the libreoffice doesn't work at all.
It shows the start screen and then it just stops... nothing else. I tried to have it running from the terminal and this is what I got:

```
libreoffice --writer

Bus error (core dumped)
```

any clues about what should I try?

Please help... otherwise I have no choice but to go back to windows... please help
Thanks!
Stelian

Comment: I'm having this same problem. And the more i search, the more i bet it is a corrupted libreoffice version. Maybe a bad compilation. This article[1] explain what a Bus Error is, and make it clear it is a memory access not aligned, ad that can be done only by a bad instruction (ergo, the code, is not a hardware problem). [1] http://udel.edu/~pconrad/cisc181h/04F/code/segfault/readme.txt

Answer (score 0):

Bus error.. An application tries to access memory that hardware is unable to access physically. Unaligned access to memory, no permissions to read/write, or that particular address does not simply exist.

My guesses..

- buggy hardware/firmware (time for bios update?)
- broken ram. if this is the case, replace the faulty memory, before it makes more damage. i've seen a situation where short circuit caused by a faulty sdram chip destroyed the motherboard.
- some exotic hardware/firmware feature causing erratic behaviour for the kernel's memory management. this is a long shot, since i'm not a kernel developer.

Hard to say, can't call this as an answer. I hope, this helps. And there is not necessarily anything wrong with your machine. Please specify, what kind of computer we are dealing with. Might help, if someone happen to have a similar computer.